# Quantile & TransformedDistribution

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics

```
xd = ExponentialDistribution[1.0];
yd = ExponentialDistribution[5.0];
td = TransformedDistribution[x/(x + y), {x \[Distributed] xd, y \[Distributed] yd}];
Mean[td]
CDF[td, z]
```

All the above works as expected. But when I do

```
Quantile[td, 0.95]
```

I get the input echoed as the answer, i.e. MMA can not do this. Same answer in 9 & 10.

Any suggestions? Known bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica does not automatically calculate the quantile (or InverseCDF) for arbitrary distributions. You need to do it.

```
xd = ExponentialDistribution[1]; (* use exact argument *)
yd = ExponentialDistribution[5]; (* use exact argument *)
td = TransformedDistribution[
   x/(x + y), {x \[Distributed] xd, y \[Distributed] yd}];

quantile[q_] = z /. Solve[{CDF[td, z] == q, 0 <= z <= 1}, z, Reals][[1]]
```

> ConditionalExpression[(5 q)/(1 + 4 q), 0 < q < 1]

```
quantile[0.95]
```

> 0.989583

```
Plot[quantile[q], {q, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

EDIT: Generalizing the problem:

```
Clear[\[Lambda]x, \[Lambda]y, td, z]

td[\[Lambda]x_, \[Lambda]y_] = TransformedDistribution[x/(x + y),
   {x \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[\[Lambda]x],
    y \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[\[Lambda]y]}];

quantile[td[\[Lambda]x_, \[Lambda]y_], q_] =
 z /. Solve[{CDF[td[\[Lambda]x, \[Lambda]y], z] == q, 0 < q < 1},
     z, Reals][[1]] // Simplify[#, {\[Lambda]x > 0, \[Lambda]y > 0}] &
```

> ConditionalExpression[(q*[Lambda]y)/([Lambda]x - q*[Lambda]x + 
>       q*[Lambda]y),     0 < q < 1]

```
({#, z = quantile[td[\[Lambda]x, \[Lambda]y], Rationalize[#]],
      z /. {\[Lambda]x -> 1., \[Lambda]y -> 
         5}} & /@
    {.5, .75, .9, .95, .99} // Simplify) //
 TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {None,
     {"\nCDF", "quantile,\ni.e.,\ninverse CDF",
      "\n{\[Lambda]x \[Rule] 1,\n \[Lambda]y \[Rule] 5}"}}] &
```

[image]

Comment: It is correct that Mathematica will not give a symbolic closed form of the InverseCDF for an arbitrary distribution, if it doesn't exist. But isn't Mathematica supposed to give a numarical value for, in this example, `InverseCDF[td,0.95]`?

Comment: @Karsten7 - Mathematica only knows what it has been told and they have elected not to tell it how to do this. For this distribution there is a closed form for the inverse CDF (quantile above) but it does not know this a priori and hasn't been told to try. Presumably because in many/most cases it might spend a lot of time and still fail; and for those cases where it will work you can easily do it.